# How do I 'validate' on destroy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

On destruction of a restful resource, I want to guarantee a few things before I allow a destroy operation to continue? Basically, I want the ability to stop the destroy operation if I note that doing so would place the database in a invalid state? There are no validation callbacks on a destroy operation, so how does one "validate" whether a destroy operation should be accepted?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520320/validate-before-destroy

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can raise an exception which you then catch. Rails wraps deletes in a transaction, which helps matters.

For example:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :booking_payments
  ....
  def destroy
    raise "Cannot delete booking with payments" unless booking_payments.count == 0
    # ... ok, go ahead and destroy
    super
  end
end
```

Alternatively you can use the before_destroy callback. This callback is normally used to destroy dependent records, but you can throw an exception or add an error instead.

```
def before_destroy
  return true if booking_payments.count == 0
  errors.add :base, "Cannot delete booking with payments"
  # or errors.add_to_base in Rails 2
  false
  # Rails 5
  throw(:abort)
end
```

`myBooking.destroy` will now return false, and `myBooking.errors` will be populated on return.

Comment: Note that where it now says "... ok, go ahead and destroy", you need to put "super", so the original destroy method is actually called.

Comment: errors.add_to_base is deprecated in Rails 3. Instead you should do errors.add(:base, "message").

Comment: Rails doesn't validate before destroying, so before_destroy would need to return false for it to cancel the destroy.  Just adding errors is useless.

Comment: With Rails 5, the `false` at the end of the `before_destroy` is useless. From now on you should use `throw(:abort)` (@see: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/1/10/This-week-in-Rails/#halting-callback-chains-by-throwing-aborthttpsgithubcomrailsrailspull17227).

Comment: Your example of defending against orphaned records can be solved much more easily via `has_many :booking_payments, dependent: :restrict_with_error`

Answer (score 49):

just a note:

For rails 3

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

before_destroy :booking_with_payments?

private

def booking_with_payments?
        errors.add(:base, "Cannot delete booking with payments") unless booking_payments.count == 0

        errors.blank? #return false, to not destroy the element, otherwise, it will delete.
end
```

Comment: A problem with this approach is that the before_destroy callback seems to be called *after* all of the booking_payments have been destroyed.

Comment: Related ticket: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3458
@sunkencity you can declare before_destroy before association declaration to temporarily avoid this.

Comment: Your example of defending against orphaned records can be solved much more easily via `has_many :booking_payments, dependent: :restrict_with_error`

Comment: Per the rails guide before_destroy callbacks can and should be placed before associations with dependent_destroy; this triggers the callback before the associated destroys are called: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object

Answer (score 22):

It is what I did with Rails 5:

```
before_destroy do
  cannot_delete_with_qrcodes
  throw(:abort) if errors.present?
end

def cannot_delete_with_qrcodes
  errors.add(:base, 'Cannot delete shop with qrcodes') if qrcodes.any?
end
```

Comment: This is a nice article that explains this behavior in Rails 5: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/13/rails-5-does-not-halt-callback-chain-when-false-is-returned.html

Comment: Your example of defending against orphaned records can be solved much more easily via `has_many :qrcodes, dependent: :restrict_with_error`

Answer (score 22):

State of affairs as of Rails 6:

This works:

```
before_destroy :ensure_something, prepend: true do
  throw(:abort) if errors.present?
end

private

def ensure_something
  errors.add(:field, "This isn't a good idea..") if something_bad
end
```

`validate :validate_test, on: :destroy` doesn't work: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32376

Since Rails 5 `throw(:abort)` is required to cancel execution: https://makandracards.com/makandra/20301-cancelling-the-activerecord-callback-chain

`prepend: true` is required so that `dependent: :destroy` doesn't run before the validations are executed: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3458

You can fish this together from other answers and comments, but I found none of them to be complete.

*As a sidenote, many used a `has_many` relation as an example where they want to make sure not to delete any records if it would create orphaned records. This can be solved much more easily:*

`has_many :entities, dependent: :restrict_with_error`

Comment: A small improvement: `before_destroy :handle_destroy, prepend: true; before_destroy { throw(:abort) if errors.present? }` will allow errors from other before_destroy validations to pass through instead of ending the destroy process immediately

Answer (score 6):

The ActiveRecord associations has_many and has_one allows for a dependent option that will make sure related table rows are deleted on delete, but this is usually to keep your database clean rather than preventing it from being invalid.

Comment: Another way to take care of underscores, if they're part of a function name or similar, is to wrap them in backticks. That will display then as code, `like_so`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer led me to another search about **types of dependent** option that was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962390/3681793

Comment: There're also `dependent` options which do not allow the removal of an entity if it would create orphaned records (this is more relevant to the question). E.g. `dependent: :restrict_with_error`

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the destroy action in an "if" statement in the controller:

```
def destroy # in controller context
  if (model.valid_destroy?)
    model.destroy # if in model context, use `super`
  end
end
```

Where *valid_destroy?* is a method  on your model class that returns true if the conditions for destroying a record are met.

Having a method like this will also let you prevent the display of the delete option to the user - which will improve the user experience as the user won't be able to perform an illegal operation.

Comment: good catch, but I was assuming this method is in the controller, deferring to the model. If it was in the model would definitely cause issues

Comment: hehe, sorry bout that... I see what you mean, I just saw "method on your model class" and quickly thought "uh oh", but you're right - destroy on the controller, that would work fine. :)

Comment: all good, in fact better to be very clear rather than make some poor beginner's life difficult with poor clarity

Comment: I thought about doing it in the Controller as well, but it really does belong on the Model so that objects cannot be destroyed from the console or any other Controller that might need to destroy those objects. Keep it DRY. :)

Comment: That being said, you can still use your `if` statement in the `destroy` action of your Controller, except instead of calling `if model.valid_destroy?`, just call `if model.destroy` and let the model handle whether the destroy was successful, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using code from here to create a can_destroy override on activerecord:
https://gist.github.com/andhapp/1761098

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def can_destroy?
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.all? do |assoc|
      assoc.options[:dependent] != :restrict || (assoc.macro == :has_one && self.send(assoc.name).nil?) || (assoc.macro == :has_many && self.send(assoc.name).empty?)
    end
  end
end
```

This has the added benefit of making it trivial to hide/show a delete button on the ui

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the before_destroy callback to raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I have these classes or models

```
class Enterprise < AR::Base
   has_many :products
   before_destroy :enterprise_with_products?

   private

   def empresas_with_portafolios?
      self.portafolios.empty?  
   end
end

class Product < AR::Base
   belongs_to :enterprises
end
```

Now when you delete an enterprise this process validates if there are products associated with enterprises
Note: You have to write this in the top of the class in order to validate it first.

Answer (score 2):

Use ActiveRecord context validation in Rails 5.

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy do
    throw :abort if invalid?(:destroy)
  end
end
```

```rb
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  validate :validate_expires_on, on: :destroy

  def validate_expires_on
    errors.add :expires_on if expires_on > Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: You cannot validate `on: :destroy`, see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49560873/4948732)

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping this would be supported so I opened a rails issue to get it added:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32376