# Ruby on Rails before_destroy causing NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to implement *before_destroy* on a model. While I am following this [*before_destroy* example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails/123190#123190) I either receive a NameError or end up with something which doesn't do the *before_destroy*. What's wrong with my syntax?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_loans, :order => 'return_date desc'
  has_many :books, :through => :book_loans

  before_destroy
    errors.add_to_base "Cannot delete borrower with loans" unless
                                                           book_loans.count == 0
end
```

**Doesn't Compile**

```
  before_destroy
    errors.add_to_base "Cannot delete borrower with loans" unless
                                                           book_loans.count == 0
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
def before_destroy
  errors.add_to_base "Cannot delete borrower with loans" unless
                                                         book_loans.count == 0
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add errors `before_destroy`, because they won't impact the validation. You have to add the errors before the validation occurs, with e.g. `before_validation`.

There are some additional callbacks, `before_validation_on_create` and `before_validation_on_update`. There is no `on_destroy` version, though, because `save` and `valid?` is never called, so adding validation errors when you try to destroy something would be pointless.

In other words: your `before_destroy` runs, but it doesn't affect anything, because nothing checks for validation errors when you destroy records.

Here's one take on implementing something that prevents record saving based on certain conditions.

```
before_destroy :require_no_book_loans

private

def require_no_book_loans
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid unless book_loans.count == 0
end
```

You could also create your own error class and raise that.

FYI: You are supposed to pass a block to `before_destroy` in your syntax error example.

```
before_destroy {|r|
  r.errors.add_to_base "Foo" # ...
}
```

Comment: So how would I prevent the destruction of a person who has loans?

Comment: Sweet so this will raise an error. Considering that exceptions should only occur in exceptional circumstances would I be better off preventing the destroy link from even showing up when the user has loans?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds sensible. People could still forge it by making a request to destroy it by hand, but you're raising an error so it won't  be destroyed anyway.