# Validate Before Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have three classes: `School`, `Account`, and `Administratorship`.

**School**

```rails
has_many :administatorships
has_many :administrators, :through => :administratorships
```

**Account**

```rails
has_many :administratorships
```

**Administratorship**

```rails
belongs_to :account
belongs_to :school

before_destroy :confirm_presence_of_alternate_administratorship_in_school

protected

def confirm_presence_of_alternate_administratorship_in_school
    unless school.administrators.count(["administratorships.account_id != #{id}"]) > 0
        errors.add_to_base "The school must have at least one administrator"
    end
end
```

Now, what I would like to happen is when I call `destroy` on an instance of `Administratorship`, for it to add an error to the model and prevent the destruction of the model. I have removed the `unless` statement to see if that was preventing the error from being added, but it wasn't the case. It seems that having errors on the model does not prevent the destroy from occurring.

So my question is, is there any way I can prevent the destroy from occurring using validations?  I realize I could define a method that destroys only if the above condition is met, but it seems that a validation approach is a more elegant solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I 'validate' on destroy in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `> 1`? Isn't this query executed *before* the delete happens?

Comment: @panzi it's it's counting any administratorships that don't have the account id of the current administratorship

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> [In case somebody stumbles here looking for Rails 5, returning false is not the way anymore. Use `throw(:abort)` instead, like in Martin Cabrera Diaubalick's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520320/validate-before-destroy#comment85795682_5520381)

---

##### Before Rails 5

If you return false from that before_destroy method, it will prevent the destruction.

Comment: For the general case where you want the object in a valid state before destroying it, you could do: `before_destroy :valid?`

Comment: Seems to raise `LocalJumpError: unexpected return` in Rails 4.1 if returning immediately, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12981 '#Fix 1'

Comment: In case somebody stumbles here looking for Rails 5, returning false is not the way anymore. Use `throw(:abort)` instead, like in Martin Cabrera Diaubalick's answer.

Answer (score 53):

This is a **Rails 5** answer, if you return false it will give a deprecation warning: *"Returning `false` in Active Record and Active Model callbacks will not implicitly halt a callback chain in Rails 5.1"*.

```
def confirm_presence_of_alternate_administratorship_in_school
  return if school.administrators.count(["administratorships.account_id != #{id}"]) > 0
  errors[:base] << 'The school must have at least one administrator'
  throw :abort
end
```

Comment: In Rails 5.1.4 I am not even seeing a deprecation warning.

Comment: @MarkFraser a lot of deprecation warnings were removed after 5.0.0 and just implemented instead

Comment: Thank you! It works! `return false` NO is a solution.

Answer (score 14):

Returning `false` from your validation method will prevent the record from getting destroyed.

**Example:**

```
def confirm_presence_of_alternate_administratorship_in_school
  unless school.administrators.count(["administratorships.account_id != #{id}"]) > 0
    # errors.add_to_base() is deprecated in Rails 3. Instead do...
    errors.add(:base, "The school must have at least one administrator")

    # this will prevent the object from getting destroyed
    return false
  end
end
```

**Side note:** I was having trouble with this error message not being displayed. The validation would work and the object would not be deleted, but there would be no message letting me know what happened. The reason for this was that the controller was redirecting to the index view instead of rendering the delete view (if there is an error while creating a new user for example, it will render :action => 'new'. In this case there is no delete view). When this happened, the instance variable on which the error message was set (in errors.add(:base,"message")) is actually being reset, which destroys the error in the process.

Comment: Is there any way to solve the issue you brought up on the Side note?

Comment: To solve the issue brought up in the **side note**, add something like the following to the `redirect_to` line in the destroy action of the relevant controller: `format.html { redirect_to products_url, :notice => "An Error Occurred! #{@products.errors[:base].to_s}" }`. And then as long as you're displaying flash messages somewhere in your app (e.g. application.html.erb) then it'll appear. See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9390778/664833).

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 5, returning`false` won't halt the callback chain. You need to use `throw(:abort)`

belongs_to :account
belongs_to :school

before_destroy :confirm_presence_of_alternate_administratorship_in_school

protected

```
def confirm_presence_of_alternate_administratorship_in_school
    unless school.administrators.count(["administratorships.account_id != #{id}"]) > 0
        errors.add_to_base "The school must have at least one administrator"
        throw(:abort)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using code from here to create a can_destroy override on activerecord: https://gist.github.com/andhapp/1761098

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def can_destroy?
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.all? do |assoc|
      assoc.options[:dependent] != :restrict || (assoc.macro == :has_one && self.send(assoc.name).nil?) || (assoc.macro == :has_many && self.send(assoc.name).empty?)
    end
  end
end
```

This has the added benefit of making it trivial to hide/show a delete button on the ui

Comment: How save is it? I almost used your solution, but solved with `dependent: :restrict_with_error`. But I still thinking how save would your solution be...