# Best practice method of displaying flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering what's the best practice for displaying flash messages.  The two main ways I've seen are using something like this scaffold generated code

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

or placing code like this in your application header.

```
<% if !flash.empty? %>
    <div id="flash"> 
        <% flash.keys.each do |k| %> 
            <div class="<%= k %>">
                <%= flash[k] %>
            </div>  
        <% end %>   
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It appears to me that the first method adds more flexibility while the latter improves code readability and eliminates redundancy.  Is there a method most rails developers prefer?  As a side question how does scaffolding implement notice?  Is it just a helper that accesses the flash hash?  Why go through the trouble of using the helper when you can directly use the flash hash?  Thanks

Comment: One thing to note is that some people use arrays as the flash value, which the solutions don't address.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm doing it this way:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "flash #{key}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does this offer any specific benefits other than less lines of code?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, it reduces the number of code lines and improves the readability of the code.

Comment: ")" after "flash #{key}" not needed, it throws error message

Comment: I think I also saw this form applied in a railscast too. Ashame railscast is dead.

Comment: I advise adding this check as well around the content tag as libraries such as Devise adds more then just alerts and notices into this structure.
            -if key == 'alert' or key == 'notice'

Answer (score 37):

Calling a partial keeps your `application.html.erb` even cleaner..

```
<%= render 'shared/flash_messages' if !flash.empty? %>
```

.. and in the partial do something like what @zolter mentioned:

```
<div id="flash_messages">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: But you can put everything in a partial then.  As I always understood you mainly only want to throw things in a partial that get repeated throughout your app.  If there are large chunks of code then yes put those into a partial as well but does this qualify as that?  I don't know and I don't have enough experience to make that call but imho I don't see the point of making a new partial for it.  Thanks

Comment: [One way to use partials is to treat them as the equivalent of subroutines: as a way to move details out of a view so that you can grasp what's going on more easily.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials-to-simplify-views)

Answer (score 2):

Why not put the second method on a helper function so it doesn't affect code readability on layouts?

Comment: I've only had to use it once in my application header but if that  got more cluttered I assume I would put it in a separate helper.  Do you know how the notice helper works, because it appears scaffolding already does this for you using that notice helper.  Thanks

Comment: You can use more than once on different projects, it's like all Rails helpers that you use once per application like csrf_mete_tags helper.

Answer (score 2):

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notification is-primary global-notification">
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:alert] %>
  <div class="notification is-danger global-notification">
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```