# Rails 4 - Error Messages for Email Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email

I am saving an email to the database and then sending it.  I am using the email model to validate the inputs, but I'm not sure how to display the error messages.  I am getting an undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass error for the fullmessage.errors.any? line in the index action(highlighted below)

View

```
<%= form_tag("/thank_you") do %>
              <% if @fullmessage.errors.any? %> # <----- This line
                <h3>Errors</h3>
                <ul>
                <% @fullmessage.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %> # Would also cause an error if exemption not already raised
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
              <% end %>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <%= text_field_tag :first_name, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <%= text_field_tag :last_name, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email Address' %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group text-area-wide">
                    <%= text_area_tag :message, nil, class: 'form-control text-area-wide', placeholder: 'When are you available?' %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <%= submit_tag 'Get Started', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
              <p><a href="http://www.skype.com/en/" target="_blank">Skype</a> required</p>
            <% end %>
```

Controller

```
def thank_you
    @first_name = params[:first_name]
    @last_name = params[:last_name]
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = params[:message] || "Hello!"
    @fullmessage = Email.create(first_name: @first_name, last_name: @last_name, email: @email, message: @message)
    if @fullmessage.valid?
      ActionMailer::Base.mail(
          :from => @email, 
            :to => 'erikvdw@comcast.net', 
            :subject => "A new contact form message from #{@first_name} #{@last_name}", 
            :body => @message).deliver
    else
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:alert] = 'There was an issue with your submission'
    end
  end
```

Model

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_length_of :first_name, :maximum => 25, :minimum => 2
  validates_length_of :first_name, :maximum => 30, :minimum => 2
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 500, :minimum => 20
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use `render` instead of redirect to (this way you'll keep your `@fullmessage` object.
2. Save error into `flash[:alert]` and display it in the view

The 2nd option is more universal, you could add the relevant code to the layout and use it across the whole site. E.g.:

```
<% if !flash.empty? %>
    <div id="flash">
      <% flash.keys.each do |k| %>
          <div class="alert alert-<%= k %>">
            <%= flash[k] %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  In response to option 1, this does not change the error I'm getting.  Maybe because @fullmessage is defined in the thank_you action.  (The error is for the index action) (edited to show this)  In regards to option 2, how would I set the key based on the validation that failed in the model?

Comment: `flash[:alert] = @fullmessage.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`

Answer (score 0):

Nil class means that the @fullmessage is nil and hasn't been set, and nil does not have the method errors, hence the error.

When you redirect, the @fullmessage value will have nothing because http is stateless.  Absent caching and cookies, every variable is recreated with every request.   think what you are trying to do is display the flash messages, if that is the case you can add the @fullmessage.errors to the flash and be able to display that on the redirect.

Comment: Thanks. Reviewing this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390778/best-practice-method-of-displaying-flash-messages) I'm not sure how to set the key for each flash message based on the validation that fails in a given situation though.  Ideas?

Comment: <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "flash #{key}" %>
<% end %>

Comment: My question probably wasn't clear.  I mean to ask how do I set the values for the keys (presumably) given by the model.  For example, I need to tell rails to give an error message that says 'Improper email format' if the validation that fails is the email validation. So rails would give me some key that indicates an error for the email field, and I would set the output.

Maybe a long list of if ifelse?  if @fullmessage.first_name.valid -> Set value to 'first name wrong' elseif @fullmessage.last_name.valid? -> Set value to 'last name wrong'?

Comment: flash[:warning] @fullmessage.full_messages.first  or you can map them if you want them all.