# Calling flash notification via JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The base rails app has flash messages that can be called via:

```
"flash.now[:error]"
```

However, how do I call it manually via JS? Here is my current code:

```
var show_error = function (message) {
  $("#flash-messages").html('<div class="flashes"> <div class="flash-notice">' + message + '</div> </div>');
  return false;
};
```

Comment: It looks to me like you have a function which can be called like this: `show_error('Something is Flasing!')` Or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default message by including it in the function. Read more about JS `||` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()

You may also want to see this answer SO: [Best practice method of displaying flash messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390778/best-practice-method-of-displaying-flash-messages)

```js
var show_error = function (message) {
  message = message || 'Something should be flashing here!';
  $("#flash-messages").html('<div class="flashes"> <div class="flash-notice">' + message + '</div> </div>');
  return false;
};

/*
show_error();
*/

/*
show_error('Something is Flashing!');
*/
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm trying to set this to true: "<% if flash.any? %>".

Comment: You asked about setting a default value. Please rephrase your question to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: I asked about calling Flash messages in JS - the same ones called by "flash.now[:error]". Thank you for your help though!