# Validate resource uniqueness and required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a Page model and a an Application model, each application should have at least one page with attribute is_about = true, so this is my actual validation rules in Page model :

```
 validates :is_about, :uniqueness => {:scope => :application_id}, :if => :is_about?
```

It works when I try to add another Page with is_about = true to application which already have a page with is_about. But when I try to remove is_about it works too.

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520320/validate-before-destroy

Comment: You think about a custom validate rule or a callback ? Yeah may be it do the trick. I'll try in a moment.

Comment: Validating the uniqueness of `:is_about` won't work anyway because it would prevent you from having two pages with `is_about = false` which I guess is a normal behavious you want to allow ;)