# Condition in before_destroy callback (Rails) does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, destroy

Condition `"unless articles.count == 0"` in `before_destroy` filter does not work.

Has anyone had similar problems?

```
class Category

has_many :articles
before_destroy :ensure_has_no_articles

private

def ensure_has_no_articles
  unless articles.count == 0
    errors[:base] << "cannot delete category that has articles"
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the behaviour you expect and what is the one that you observe?

Comment: if Category has no articles, it should prevent category deletion. If has no articles, it should allow category deletion

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Category

has_many :articles
before_destroy :ensure_has_no_articles

private

def ensure_has_no_articles
    return true if articles.count == 0
    errors[:base] << "cannot delete category that has articles"
    return false
end
```

**Update:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :dependent => :restrict_with_error
```

Comment: no, it does not work even if I place only return false without any conditions. I use MongoDB, can it be the case of my issue?

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I use Rails 5          .

Answer (score 0):

As stated in an answer to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5520381/580346 you need to return `true` if you want that the destroy is called. Your `ensure_has_no_articles` always returns `false`. The answer provided by @sunil-b-n should help you.

You may also like: [Validate Before Destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520320/validate-before-destroy)

Answer (score 0):

This method was deprecated according to [this rails issue](https://gist.github.com/claudiob/614c59409fb7d11f2931#explicitly-halt-callback-chains)

The best way to solve this by

```
class Category

has_many :articles
before_destroy :ensure_has_no_articles

private

def ensure_has_no_articles
  unless articles.count == 0
    errors[:base] << "cannot delete category that has articles"
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```