# how to communicate which of multiple before_* callbacks halts execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

before_* callbacks can halt execution by returning false.

I have 3 before_destroy callbacks on a model to halt destruction for several possible reasons. I'd like to tell the user which reason it is, but I'll I get back from the model.destroy is false. How can I send a message out of the model, or determine from the controller which before_destroy callback halted execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice question. I don't know if there is a good way to do it. The only thing that comes to my mind is using errors[:base] but it sounds a bit of a hack.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a hack at all.  I'd consider this the exactly right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are few good answers here - [How do I 'validate' on destroy in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails).

Basicly the solutions will be

```
errors.add_to_base "Name of the error"
```

OR

You can define attr_accessor in the model and set them appropriately , even thought I think that this is not the most DRY way , because the object already has the errors attribute hash which should hold the errors.

EX is:

```
attr_accessor :before_save_error1
attr_accessor :before_save_error2
attr_accessor :before_save_error3

before_destroy :check_for_errors

def check_for_errors 
  error = false
  if error1 # some condition here 
    self.before_save_error1 = true
    error = true 
  elsif error2 # some condition here 
    self.before_save_error2 = true
    error = true
  elseif error3 # some condition here 
    self.before_save_error3 = true
    error = true   
  end 

  error
end
```

Comment: add_to_base is depricated, but I like the accessor idea

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use:

> errors.add :my_key, 'my msg'

Errors is just a hash and can handle any key. Just make sure you don't have name collisions with your attributes.

Comment: Yep... it's what I was suggesting ;)