# How to prevent has_and_belongs_to_many delete option from deleting records that are being used in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
end
```

In console:

```
part1 = Part.new
assembly1 = Assembly.new
assembly1.parts << part1
part1.delete
Parts.all
 => []
```

Checking `assembly1.parts` shows that there is still a relationship.(!)

How is this possible when the record was deleted?

Also, how to prevent deletion of parts that are associated to assemblies?

Working in Rails 3.0.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you were doing here was done from memory (nothing was stored in the database).

the ActiveRecord `delete` method will remove an object from the database but it doesn't look for other objects in memory that may have already been referencing that object.  I think if you did `assembly1.parts.delete(part1)` that would likely do what you were expecting.

If you had saved the objects to the database:

```
part1 = Part.create
assembly1 = Assembly.create(:parts => [part1])
assembly1.parts
# => [part1]
part1.delete
assembly1.parts
# => [part1]
assembly1.reload
assembly1.parts
# => []
```

Note here how even if it's in the database `part1.delete` won't necessarily remove it from your assembly object until you refresh the in-memory collection or delete it using the method I mentioned earlier `assembly1.parts.delete(part1)`

UPDATE

I think you *usually* shouldn't use the `delete()` method.  You should almost always use `destroy()`.  `delete()` will just fire off a delete to the database and ignores all callbacks and I believe `:dependent => :destroy`-style declarations in your model.  If you use the `destroy()` method then you can declare a `before_destroy` callback in your model:

```
class MyClass
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos

  before_destroy :allow_destroy

  def allow_destroy
    foos.empty?
  end
end
```

That should get your requirement of not destroying it if it is part of an assembly.  You cannot stop `delete()` from executing because it ignores callbacks:  [ActiveRecord::Relation#delete documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete)

More info about [model callbacks (documentation)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `:dependent => :destroy` to the controller.

Comment: Actually, instead of deleting the dependent records, I want the delete action to fail and flash the reason: "Cannot delete part because it is being used by one or more assemblies."

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent `myobject.delete` in the database by adding some [referential integrity](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity) with a [foreign key](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys).
I recommend looking at [Adding foreign key to a rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31882059/11710789)

in my project this did not prevent `myobject.destroy`. I think this is because it uses the [awesome nested set gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) tries really hard to handle cascading destroy for you.

to prevent `myobject.destroy`
I found [How do I 'validate' on destroy in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails#123190) supper helpful

I ended up using an `before_destroy` as well as adding some referential integrity with `add_foreign_key` in a migration. 
this will prevent deletion if `myobject.delete` is used or if `myobject.destroy` is used.

in my case `myobject` hads many of itself and belongs to one of itself. this is what `act_as_nested_set` handles.

**Model**

```
class Myobject
  before_destroy :allow_destroy
  # ^ this has to be above act_as_nested_set
  acts_as_nested_set

  def allow_destroy
    return true if self.descendants.blank?
    # the error is optional. 
    self.errors.add('Cannot_delete', 'myobject still has children')
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

**Migration**

```
class AddForignKeyToMyobject < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key :myobject, :myobject, column: :parent_id
  end
end
```