# add relationship in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

i have two table
subject and subject element that i create with help of scaffold 
after that i want to add relationship between subject and subject_element

it possible to add relationship using scaffold?

or any other way we can add?

i tried this solution [Adding foreign key to a rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257116/adding-foreign-key-to-a-rails-model) but not add successfully

please help i new in ruby on rails 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have got two models(subject, element)
I am trying to add following has-to-many association: 
 1.One subject can have multiple elements 
 2. one element belongs to one subject.

create those models from console :

```
rails g model subject number:string name:string 

rails g model element element_number:string part_number:string subject:references
```

check your migrations: (below migration will be automatically added when you create the element model by above migration)

```
 #app/db/migrate/XXXXX_create_elements.rb
class CreateElements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :elements do |t|
      t.string :element_number
      t.string :part_number
      t.references :subject, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :elements, :subjects
  end
end
```

Now check your model files :

```
 #app/model/subject.rb
 class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :elements
 end

 #app/model/element.rb 
  class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :subject #note-this one will be automatically added 
  end
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i am already create app using this command          " sudo ruby script/generate scaffold subject_element id:decimal sub_ele_name:text des:text"   so it will create crud operation view also now i want to add one relation between subject and subject_element

Comment: this one fixed your issue ?

Comment: I would say no don't do it manually. if you already have the table/model then do consider adding a new column(using migration only). that's how rails work ! :)

Comment: Still, if you insist on doing it manually, make sure you migrate down -> do manual change -> migrate up!

Comment: i try to edit manually to migration file as per your file and model file also and then "run rake db:migrate " after that i add    "<%= f.label :subject %></div><br />   <%= f.select :subject, Subject.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] } %> " in new.html.erb  so when i press create button it will give following error   "  ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Subject elementsController#create

Subject(#69925002548940) expected, got String(#69925048599560) "

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted "Adding foreign key to a Rails model" is indeed the right way, but you still need to do a bit of config.

If you are using anything below Rails 4, you should have an `attr_accessible` on your `subject_element.rb` model. If not, add it. And add `subject_id` to the list so that it looks like this:

```
class SubjectElement < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :subject_id

...
```

Note that it's a list so multiple entries would look like this (example)

```
attr_accessible :title, :subject_id
```

And then, remember to add the `has_many` and `belongs_to` helpers:

```
 class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :elements
 end

 class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject 
 end
```

if you are still struggling, please post me your `subject.rb`, `subject_element.rb` and the **migration**