# Rails Unconventional DB Structure, is this problematic for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

My company's old team leader had fairly little knowledge of Ruby on Rails and used weird convention for the db structure for associations.

Let's say I have a `User` model and a `Role` model, and that a user belongs to a role.

What I would consider typical:

```
rails g migration AddRoleToUsers role:references

# app/models/user.rb
belongs_to :role

# app/models/role.rb
has_many :users
```

But I can clearly see that something else has happened.

Whenever I `User.new`, I get something like:

```
#<User stuffs, role_id: nil>
```

In the models I've got

```
# app/models/user.rb
belongs_to :role, :class_name => 'Role', :foreign_key => :role_id

# app/models/role.rb
has_many :users
```

This pattern litters a good part of our application. I can tell that these columns are index, but don't actually have a foreign keys.

First question, is this problematic? To me, this implies referential integrity issues.

Second question, how can I add a foreign key after the fact and preserve existing data?

I'm using a gem called data-migration, which I hope can help me preserve the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a verbose way of writing what Rails will do automatically by convention.

In the `User.role` relationship, this:

```
belongs_to :role, :class_name => 'Role', :foreign_key => :role_id
```

is equivalent to this:

```
belongs_to :role
```

Rails can infer the class_name and foreign_key based on the name of the relationship.  It's just a redundancy that won't hurt in this case.

The `foreign_key` is actually the name of the field that's used to store the `id` value for the relationship, it's not a database foreign key at all.

You can add a database foreign key for these relationships by creating a migration or each table that you want to update.  There's a great answer for that in [Adding foreign key to a rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257116/adding-foreign-key-to-a-rails-model) that gives the step-by-step instructions to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up figuring this out. You're right about the association in the model being a verbose version of the same thing. Since naming convention was followed, I safely removed these.

Comment: As a side note for anyone facing this issue, rename the `_id` columns. This way you can add your foreign key, then reassign any previous information back to the reference. Once that is done, you can safely remove the column and know that all your data is safe!