# adding a foreign key field to an existing table in a different gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I would like to add foreign key fields ('completed_by') to an existing table pointing to a 
 different gem, by updating a migration file and a models file.

Migration file:

```
class CreateToDoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :to_do_items do |t|
      t.references :event, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.integer :priority
      t.string  :name
      t.boolean :done
      t.date  :issued_on
      t.date  :to_complete_on
      t.string  :comment
      t.integer :completed_by, null: true, foreign_key: true
      t.text    :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Models file:

```
class ToDoItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :person_company, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding foreign key to a rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257116/adding-foreign-key-to-a-rails-model)

Comment: Thank you Jvillian for editing my question text, everything went wrong and I was not able to correct the text. The entries in the migration and models files, didn't help me get what I was expecting to. I would be more than happy to provide further information. Thanks.