# Rails 4 association validate destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, simple-form

I have two models with many-to-many association through third model.
By ex:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

And using simple_form i have this checkbox set (Physician form):

```
...
= f.association :patients, as: :check_boxes
...
```

When i check some checkboxes, after save rails will create appointments in database.

When i uncheck checkboxes, rails will destroy some unchecked appointments.

So update will be eq to

```
physician.patient_ids = []
```

I want to validate appointments before delete. By example if appointments have some warnings, i want to show alert validation error on saving Physician form.

So, i thought, maybe rails will call destroy method on appointments, and tried:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

before_destroy :check_destroy
private
def check_destroy
  raise 'you can not do it!'
end
```

Nope, rails just removed appointments from database on save Physician.

Maybe rails will use delete method? Then i tried this one:

```
  class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def delete
    raise 'you can not do it!'
  end
```

Nope, again.

Seems to rails just remove join-association (appointment) straight from database.

How to prevent it? I want to validate all appointments that will be deleted before saving Physician, and add error to Physician if some appointments can not be deleted.

Comment: Do any of the methods in the following post work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails

Comment: @rodamn if i call destroy on Physician, i think it will works by dependent: :destroy. But in my case, i don't calling destroy, but just calling save on model in controller #update action with set of ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the rails [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> Similar to the normal callbacks that hook into the life cycle of an
>   Active Record object, you can also define callbacks that get triggered
>   when you add an object to or remove an object from an association
>   collection.

Example from Docs

```
class Project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :developers, after_add: :evaluate_velocity

  def evaluate_velocity(developer)
    ...
  end
end
```

So in your particular scenario try

```
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments, before_remove :check_remove
```

Comment: yes, it helps, but callback method calls before_remove, not before_destroy