# Rails - Cancel destroy on before_destroy callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

is there any way, given certain condition, cancel the destroy of an object on the before_destroy callback of active record? Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should return `false`.

## Rails 5

"Canceling callbacks

If a before_* callback throws :abort, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled."

## Rails 4 and lower

"Canceling callbacks

If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last."

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: With Rails 5, returning false no longer works. One should `throw(:abort)` to prevent record deletion. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails#comment59333149_123190)

Comment: Thanks for specifying the :abort technique for Rails 5. Should really help me out.

Comment: I've searched forever to find this answer - it's not even clear from the official documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotDestroyed.html - thanks!

Comment: For rails 3, returning false just skips the other callbacks but it destroys the actual object. Anyone?

Answer (score 10):

As none of the given answers really solves the problem, but the comment above tells it - here the in form of an answer to make it easy to find:

**In rails 5, instead of**

```
before_destroy do
  if self.some_condition?
    return false
  end
end
```

**use**

```
before_destroy do
  if self.some_condition?
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

to make sure destroy is not being perfomed.

thanks to [RFVoltolini's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails#comment59333149_123190) - this saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Rails wraps saves and destroys in a transaction, so a `raise` in the callback would work:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :saveable?

  def saveable?
    if true
      raise "Destroy aborted; you can't do that!"
    end
  end
end
```

Substitute `true` for your condition.

Here's the abridged console output:

```
[1] pry(main)> Post.first.id
=> 1
[2] pry(main)> Post.first.destroy
RuntimeError: Destroy aborted; you can't do that!
[3] pry(main)> Post.first.id
=> 1
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-save+and+destroy+are+automatically+wrapped+in+a+transaction)

Comment: thnks, but don't want it raise anything... just do nothing

Comment: Makes sense. Because this is a `before_*` callback, either `raise` or `false` works. The benefit of a `raise` is that you'll get a clear message you can trace in the logs, rather than the `destroy` quietly not happening. Which to choose depends on how unexpected your failure case may be.

Comment: In Rails 5, you will have to explicitly `raise :abort`. You might as well start now.

Comment: In Rails 5, `raise :abort` doesn't work for me. I think it *has* to be `throw :abort`

Answer (score 3):

Returning `false` is the way to do it properly:

```
before_destroy do
  if self.some_condition?
    return false
  end
end
```

You can see the documentation here under point `6 Halting Execution`.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the `#destroy` method:

```
def destroy
  study_assignments.empty? ? super : raise("can not be destroyed")
end
```