# Rails validate association count before removing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel, ruby-on-rails-5

My models are

```
class Company
  has_many :admins

  validate :has_one_admin_validation

  private

  def has_one_admin_validation
    errors.add(:admins, :not_enough) if admins.size < 1
  end

end

class Admin
  belong_to :company
end
```

Now, suppose I have a controller that can remove admins. How do I prevent removing the admin (ie generate errors) if it is the only admin of its company ?

If I understand well, I have to remove the admin from the memory object, and try to "save/destroy" if by validating the company first ?

Comment: notice there is [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: hmm but maybe this validation belongs to the Admin class , not sure though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom validation at all on the Company model.  You can use the 'length' validation on your association.

```
validates :admins, length: { minimum: 1 }
```

If that doesn't work, you should also be able to check the 'marked_for_destruction?' property.  You should also be able to validate the reciprocal relationship with a 'presence: true' validation.

```
    class Company
        has_many :admins

        validate :has_one_admin_validation

        private

        def has_one_admin_validation
          errors.add :admins, "You need at least one admin" if admins.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).empty?
        end

    end

    class Admin
        belongs_to :company, presence: true
    end
```

You may also want to look at using the before_destroy callback in your Admin class.

```
before_destroy :has_company_with_no_other_admins
        ...

        private

        def has_company_with_no_other_admins
          return false if company.admins.length < 2
          true
        end
```

There's a pretty good description of using before_destroy here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/123190/6441528
That's worth looking at because implementations vary based on your Rails version.

Comment: hmmm will this validation run on Admin delete ? notice that the validation is present in Category class or maybe it should be put in the Admin Class ?

Comment: Hi! I'm not OP but I have a project where I can use something like this. Say that I have a model with a has_one associated model, will this help me enforce a limit of 1 associations for that model?

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos `has_one` alone is enough, no need for validations, in fact adding more than 1 will result in a Ruby runtime exception(NoMethodError perhaps)

Comment: The thing is, in that project somehow I'm able to establish more than one relationship even though my models have has_one/belongs_to. I think it's a goof on my side then, so no worries :^)

Comment: @niceman - I think you may be correct that I misunderstood the question somewhat and didn't add the reciprocal validation to Admin.  I've edited my answer accordingly to add the 'presence:true' modifier to the Admin class.

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos - I agree with niceman  -- I think that should work.  If you're still having problems, perhaps you should post your code in a new question so people can look at it in context.

Comment: Shouldn't the `before_destroy` check for `company.admins.length < 2` then ? `<2` means there's still another admin for the company in case the current one gets destroyed ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris - yes, you are right since the callback gets processed before the record is actually destroyed.

Comment: Oh also, since I am on Rails 5, I need to `throw(:abort)` right ?

Comment: Yes, Rails 5 requires an actual error to be thrown in this case.