# Check if there's dependency before_destroy rails admin ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am currently doing a project and in our project there's 2 table/classes ActivityType and Activity. Also in this project, we've use a gem called rails admin. The administrator can't delete a activity type if there's an activity type used in the activity.

**Activity**

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity_type
end
```

**Activity Type**

```
class ActivityType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities
before_destroy :ensure_has_no_activity_type

  private

  def ensure_has_no_activity_type
      unless activities.count == 0
       errors[:base] << "cannot delete activity type that has activity"
       return false
    end
  end
end
```

Question: How can I check if there's a child in activity? Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Is it giving error?

Comment: It doesnt return any error but it will continue to delete.

Comment: Try replacing the unless block with just `activities.present?`

Comment: So I'll delete the unless activities.count == 0 then make it activities.present? If yes, it will continue to delete :(

Comment: Sorry, i meant other way..check answer..which rails version by the way?

Comment: My version of rails is 5.0

Comment: Ok..did that work? If not, try out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37880585/6548745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i meant

```
def ensure_has_no_activity_type
  if activities.present?
    errors.add(:base, 'Cannot delete activity type that has activity')
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

Comment: It didn't work, correct me if I am wrong.. :base is the name of the model right? I also tried to use errors.add(:base, 'message: Cannot delete activity type that has activity')

Comment: remove quotes, message is key: .`errors.add(:base, message: 'Cannot delete activity type that has activity')` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

Comment: I also tried errors.add(:base, message: "Cannot delete activity type that has activity") didnt change.. I restart my server too

Comment: what do you mean by didn't change?

Comment: if you want your rails admin to display that message, that's a flash message which needs to be overridden, that seems to be whole different question. By the above method you will get message in `object.errors.message`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort again sir.. God Bless :)

Comment: have you found a way to show the custom message on rails admin when the validation fails?