# Why throwing abort in a nested association raises “Failed to destroy the record” exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to validate if any CameraVectors has been associated to any MonitoredPlace before I destroy a Camera.

Camera's Model

```
class Camera < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :camera_vectors, inverse_of: :camera, dependent: :destroy

  validates :description, :device_serial, :device_name, 
    :device_type, :device_api_url, :device_user, :device_password,
    presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :camera_vectors, allow_destroy: true
end
```

CameraVector's model

```
class CameraVector < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :camera, inverse_of: :camera_vectors
  belongs_to :monitored_place, optional: true

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :position, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }, presence: true

  before_destroy :has_monitored_place?

  private

  def has_monitored_place?
    if monitored_place.present?
      errors.add(:base, "cannot delete")
      throw :abort
    end
  end
end
```

MonitoredPlace's model

```
class MonitoredPlace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :place_type
  has_many :camera_vectors

  validates :place_name, presence: true
  validates :place_type_id, uniqueness: { scope: :location_id }, presence: true

  scope :enabled, -> { where.not(enabled_on: nil).where(disabled_on: nil) }
end
```

Because of the accepts_nested_attributes_for whenever I try to update or destroy a camera this nested fields are sent as params

```
"camera_vectors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"description"=>"A", "position"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"47"}}
```

I thought If I wrote a callback before_destroy in the model CameraVector I could validate it, but if the validation occurs it raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed in the controller.

```
if @camera.destroy(camera_params)
  redirect_to(action: :index, notice: t(".success"))
else
  render :index
end
```

Answer (score 2):

as you can read in the [api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotDestroyed.html)

> ## ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
>
> Raised by ActiveRecord::Base#destroy! when a call to #destroy would return false.

It is result of

```
before_destroy :has_monitored_place?
```

that calls a method and returns `false`.

```
def has_monitored_place?
 if monitored_place.present?
   errors.add(:base, "cannot delete")
   throw :abort
 end
end
```

to change this behavior implement a logic similar to the one described in the api

```
begin
  complex_operation_that_internally_calls_destroy!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed => invalid
  puts invalid.record.errors
end
```

or read

[How do I 'validate' on destroy in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails#123190)