# Prevent deletion of records where a certain field is non-blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

If I have a Widget model as follows:

```
create_table "widgets", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "quantity"
end
```

... how do I prevent a destroy action if `quantity` is something other than nil or zero? I assume this is something I should do in the model rather than the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
class Widget < ApplicationRecord

  before_destroy :ensure_quantity_blank

protected

  def ensure_quantity_blank
    if !self.quantity.blank?
      errors.add(:quantity, "Cannot delete widget with a quantity")
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end

end
```

See also [How do I 'validate' on destroy in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123078/how-do-i-validate-on-destroy-in-rails)